# Union of two relations according to their size

Tags: apache-pig

Currently i am combining two relations according to records they contain.
But is their exists some other way in pig to combine two relations according to number of records they contain?

Comment: This is very ambiguous. Could you provide some sample expected input/output?

Comment: Like if i have 400 records in one relation and 600 record in second relation, then union of two relations should give me resulting relation with 1000 records in which each 100 records will contain 40 records from first relation and 60 records from second relation.